# %20 Is Displayed Passing Name

Tags: php

I have a php application to send mail when i pass name to mail with more than words it displays %20 in between words.How can i remove this to space?

This is my result

```
xxxxxx%20YYYYYYYYYY
```

Comment: You've not provided any relevant details of how your script ptocesses the data nor any code.

Comment: Please paste the code you use to send email.

Comment: What do you mean by **passing name to mail** and %20 is displayed where? in the mail client of the recipient? If you shared your code, you could get immediate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `urldecode($yourstring);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something as simple as [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Note that: The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results.